# How can I have a (semi) transparent background in GTK Sharp?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

How can I have a (semi) transparent background in GTK Sharp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C it's `gtk_window_set_opacity(window, 0.5);` I don't know if this function is wrapped in Gtk#.

Comment: @mhutch why don't you put it as another answer? It works like a charm!

Comment: deprecated since version 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Since Gtk version 3.8 (released in 2013) you shall use gtk_widget_set_opacity() method instead. They have the same prototype (ofc GtkWidget pointer instead of GtkWindow).

While on Windows it shall always work, on X11 this has any effect only on X screens with a compositing manager running.